# what is it called when a program talks with other programs or other computers

Tags: network-programming

As a true beginner, one often finds that the barrier to further knowledge is not knowing what to google.

I've made programs like pong and a sudoku solver, simple things. These days I would like to work on something more like tabslock or make a multiplayer pong, or at least start thinking about what that would involve.

So what exactly is it called when programs cause other programs to do this or that, or when a program talks with a copy of itself on another computer somewhere else in this vast internet.

z.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect that searching for server/client examples and socket programming in general will get you headed in the right direction.

For example, a google search for [`socket client server c`](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=socket+client+server+c) will get you to [An Introduction to Socket Programming](http://www.uwo.ca/its/doc/courses/notes/socket/).

A similar search for [`socket client server java`](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=socket+client+server+java) gets you to a [Lesson on Socket Communications](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/socket.html)

Answer (score 4):

Network communication, TCP/IP communication, etc.

Try googling for "socket server examples in "

Answer (score 4):

I think in a very general sense you're talking about [Inter-Process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocess_communication).

Answer (score 3):

The current posts are good, also Remote Method Invocation (RMI) or Web Services, SOAP could also be useful. Also Remote Procedure Call (RPC), as in XML-RPC.

Answer (score 3):

- *sockets* are logical slots in the OS for running programs (processes) to use for communication.
- *protocols* are languages, encodings, etc. that are agreed upon by both sides of such a communication, and are used to make sense of the data.
- *remote procedure calling* or RPC is when a process in one place causes another process in another place to run some code, as if one had just called a function on the other.  This can be done over the network.
- *XML-RPC* and *SOAP* are two protocols for doing RPC over the web, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

**SkyNet** or, if you prefer, **Colossus/Guardian**.

Answer (score 0):

How about Peer-to-Peer networking, just using Sockets?

Answer (score 0):

In a more general sense you may want to look up "Service-Oriented Architecture" (SOA) a service is a program, and a given service on 1 machine, can communicate with other services on other machines.

Comment: A bit weighty a concept for a muliplayer Pong game